# video and text uploading in android

Tags: php, android

http://www.mayanklangalia.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-upload-image-audio-and-video-on.html this link helps me to upload video in database also. I want to send edittext with video. does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: did you try something or is there any specific part code while text edit that you are facing problem with?

Comment: no, I am new in android.. so i don't know how to pass text similar to upload file in above url.

Comment: can u please suggest me how to upload video with text?It's urgent for me...

Comment: I have tried to do this? but it's not working pls help me.... conn.setRequestProperty("edittext",editText.getText().toString()); dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens+boundary+lineEnd);dos.writeBytes("ContentDisposition:formdata;name=\"edittext\""+lineEnd);dos.writeBytes(""+editText);dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);